# Knockout.js console.log observable array

Tags: arrays, logging, knockout.js, console, observable

tried to console.log the stage of the observable array content via JSON.stringify as usual, but no success. I see the length changes, but not the content.

Code:

```
arr.push(new Course('New title ' + randomCourse, 'New price ' + randomCourse));
console.log('CourseList: ' + arr().length + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(arr()));
```

Console:

```
CourseList: 5 | [{},{},{},{},{}]
CourseList: 7 | [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
CourseList: 9 | [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
CourseList: 11 | [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use ko.toJS() to convert the observable properties into values:

```
console.log('CourseList: ' + arr().length + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(arr())));
```

Comment: Simple and bulletproof. Working, thanks. It will be also need to read about fromJS. Just newbee in knockout.

Comment: Hm, suddenly became not so simple and absolutely no any errors in debug.

Comment: Not exactly clear why it's not working just in this funtion. Ok in the jthers. It's better to write ko.toJSON(arr), not to minimize the code and the brackets chaos, not JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(arr()))).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, suddenly became not so simple and absolutely no any errors in debug.

Task is to push the array items to obsarvable array before other manipuletion.

Function (console if commented):

```
this.startCoursesList = function () {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        startCourses.forEach(function (item, i) {
            arr.push(new Course(startCourses[i].title, startCourses[i].price, startCourses[i].reqs));
        });
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(arr())));
    }
};
```

Everything working great, console is clear, but everything failed if I use JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(arr())). Suddenly I got the finction execution loop and arr.length check if not working. I also got the loop in console on any click event:

```
[{"title":"HTML/CSS","price":32000,"reqs":["Internet","Notepad++"]},{"title":"Yoga","price":7000,"reqs":[""]},{"title":"Darts","price":9500,"reqs":["Bomb","Worms"]}]
[{"title":"HTML/CSS","price":32000,"reqs":["Internet","Notepad++"]},{"title":"Yoga","price":7000,"reqs":[""]},{"title":"Darts","price":9500,"reqs":["Bomb","Worms"]}]
[{"title":"HTML/CSS","price":32000,"reqs":["Internet","Notepad++"]},{"title":"Yoga","price":7000,"reqs":[""]},{"title":"Darts","price":9500,"reqs":["Bomb","Worms"]}]
```

Comment: I think your question is not so clear and perhaps the information you provide is not enough to help you. The best thing would be to reproduce and share the problem in a fiddle (jsfiddle, codepen, etc.).

Comment: Yes, you're right https://jsfiddle.net/Max_A/2h7cped3/20. console.log(ko.toJSON(arr)) commented in JS str.313. Working Ok in str. 362. Thanks for your attention.